# Bash numbering CSV content on unique field

Tags: bash, sorting

I'm trying to sort a CSV file based on the first column, adding a column with a count for each instance of a unique value. It's a counter for each unique value.

```
 DT_12341234, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
 DT_12341231, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
 DT_12341231, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
 DT_12341232, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
 DT_12341234, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
 DT_12341233, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
 DT_12341234, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
 DT_12341233, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
 DT_12341233, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
 DT_12341234, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
```

Here's the output would look something like this :

```
 1, DT_12341231, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
 2, DT_12341231, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
 1, DT_12341232, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
 1, DT_12341233, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
 2, DT_12341233, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
 3, DT_12341233, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
 1, DT_12341234, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
 2, DT_12341234, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
 3, DT_12341234, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
 4, DT_12341234, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
```

I tried doing this with awk, uniq and sort, with no luck so far. Nor did I find a case similar to mine on Stack Overflow or other forums. Would appreciate being guided in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `sort` and `awk`:

```
sort file -V | awk '{ print ++a[$1] "," $0 }'
```

If every line doesn't begin with an extra space, change `","` to `", "`.

Output:

```
1, DT_12341231, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
2, DT_12341231, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
1, DT_12341232, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
1, DT_12341233, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
2, DT_12341233, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
3, DT_12341233, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
1, DT_12341234, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
2, DT_12341234, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
3, DT_12341234, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
4, DT_12341234, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
```

Comment: As a follow-up question, I have some fields that have a blank date field. I would like them to be listed in the end during the sort, rather than at the top. I see that the sort command has a -b option for ignoring blank lines. Any idea if I can modify the command you suggested to do this? Thanks.

Comment: @Soucrit Try `sort -V -t, -k 2r file`

Answer (score 1):

awk and sort without storing all first fields into array:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'p!=$1{i=1} p==$1{i++} {p=$1; print i, $0}' < <(sort -t, -k1 file.csv)
1, DT_12341231, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
2, DT_12341231, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
1, DT_12341232, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
1, DT_12341233, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
2, DT_12341233, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
3, DT_12341233, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
1, DT_12341234, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
2, DT_12341234, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
3, DT_12341234, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
4, DT_12341234, 2014/02/22 10:04:01
```